# Get the input value on clicking the button in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input field

```
<div class="inputs">
      <label>Online Payment ID</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="payId">
</div>
```

I have one  button some where in the page say

```
 <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="proceedPayment()" ></button>
```

now on clicking `proceedPayment()` will be called, from there i need to check the value use entered on above text fild

I tried,

```
 $scope.proceedPayment = function () {
      alert($scope.payId); // Always alerts undefined
     if (!$scope.payId) {
                 $scope.payIdError = true;
                 console.log('No value entered');
            } else {
                 $scope.payIdError = false;
                 console.log('value entered');
            }
 }
```

but this not working
I dont wan to use form here. I'm a angular beginner, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Satpal typo error!

Comment: Initialise `$scope.payId` before accessing it in the function. Like this: `$scope.payId = 10`

Comment: you can use a form, and then, use angular validation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use the `$scope.payId` that will contain the user entered value

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ixaEhnFAfkVjb8wo06RJ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the object

```
$scope.pay = {payId:null};


if($scope.pay.payId == null) {
   console.log("Value not entered");
} else {
      console.log("Value entered");
  }
```